# Are onchain storage reads cheaper from offchain worker versus from extrinsic?

Tags: storage, weight, offchain-worker

Are reads from offchain workers less expensive than reads from extrinsics? I am determining how to do some large, asynchronous processing of data and determining whether the reads in this process see any gain from happening in offchain worker.